# Where does Spring Webflux create a coroutine scope when using suspend functions?

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, internals

This is a question about how Spring Webflux works under the hood.

When we build our Spring Webflux application in kotlin we can use suspend functions and interfaces like CoroutineCrudRepository to ‘get rid of’ abstractions such as Mono and Flux. However, we do not need to explicitly create a coroutine scope somewhere so it seems that Spring takes care of that. Where does Spring create this coroutine scope?

I would guess that a new scope is created when a request comes in and Spring then checks if the router or controller uses suspend functions. I cant find it anywhere in the code though.